# Omitting NA in specific rows when analyzing data from 2 columns of a very large dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio, na

I am very new to R and I am struggling to understand how to omit NA values in a specific way.

I have a large dataframe with several columns (up to 40) and rows (up to 200ish). I want to use data from one of the columns to do simple stats (wilcox.test, boxplot, etc): one column will have a continuous variable (V1), while the other has a binary variable (V2; 0 or 1), which divides 2 groups. I want to do this for the continuous variable using different V2 binary variables, which are unrelated. I organized this data in Excel, saved it as CSV and am using R Studio.

All these columns have interspersed NA values and when I use omit.na, it just takes off every single row where a NA value is present, which takes away an awful load of data. Is there any simple solution to do this? I have seen some answers to similar topics, but none seems quite exactly what I need to do.

Many thanks for any answer. Again, I am a baby-level newbie to R and may have overlooked something in other topics!

Comment: So what would be your desired output then? You want to remove a whole row depending on `NA` values only in certain columns instead of the whole data set?

Comment: Hi David! Exactly, I want to omit every paired result, ie, if I have a NA in any one row considering only the two columns of interest (V1 and V2, than V1 and V3 and so forth), I want to omit the entire row so that the wilcox test will work, without having to make separate CSVs for each of the pairs of columns and running na.omit in each of those df. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want to apply to function to a pair of column each time.

```
 wilcox.test(V1,V2)
 wilcox.test(V1,V3)...
```

Where Vi have no missing values. I would do something like this :

```
## use complete.cases to assert that you have no missing values 
## for the selected pair
apply_clean <- 
function(x,y){
       ok <- complete.cases(x, y)
       wilcox.test(x[ok],dat$V1[ok])
}
## apply this function to all columns after removing the continuous column
lapply(subset(dat,select=-V1),apply_clean,y=dat$V1)
```

Comment: Hi again, just a little clarification: if I work (do wilcox,boxplot, etc) on V1 and V2, then V1 and V3, and so forth (where V1 is continuous and V2/3/etc are binary) will I be working with the same V1, or will the na omissions "stack", ie, when I work on V1 and V3 I have NAs(V2)+NAs(V3) instead of NAs(V3) only? Sorry if this sounds basic, but I'm still getting to grips with R. Many thanks!

Comment: One other issue: V1 does also have NA values. Sorry for not being clear. Ideally, I would actually have "several" V1s ie, several columns with continuous variables of interest, which would then be tested when divided by binary groups in "several" V2s.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the data.frame to omit based on any rules you like. For example:

```
dirty.frame <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,NA,9,10), col2 = c(10, 9, 8, 7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
cleaned.frame <- dirty.frame[!is.na(dirty.frame$col1),]
```

This code used is.na() to test if a row in a specific column is na. The ! means not, and will omit that row.